# Is using document.write the only possible way to load a script synchronously cross browser cross domain?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser

I want to mimick this behavior:

```
<script src="console.log.1.js"></script>
<script>console.log(2)</script>
<script>console.log(3)</script>
```

That logs out:

```
1
2
3
```

Doing this doesn't work:

```
<script>
var x = document.createElement("script");
x.src = "console.log.1.js";
x.async = false;
x.defer = false;
document.body.appendChild(x);
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
</script>
```

It logs out:

```
2
3
1
```

The only way I found so far to achieve it:

```
<script>
document.write("<scrip" + "t src='console.log.1.js'></scrip" + "t>");
</script>
<script>
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
</script>
```

Is that really the only way to force synchronous loading of external scripts in all browsers? Why doesn't setting async=false, defer=false work?

**UPDATE**

FYI, if someone is wondering, the following document.write inception works (in Chrome..):

```
<script>
  // http://jsbin.com/avatiw logs "during"
  document.write('<scrip' + 't>console.log("before");document.write("<scrip" + "t src=\\"http://jsbin.com/avatiw\\"></scrip" + "t>");</scrip' + 't>');
  document.write('<scrip' + 't>console.log("after");</scrip' + 't>');
</script>
```

Works and logs out:

```
"before"
"during"
"after"
```

Comment: Have you considered using `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(x);`? But even then, is there a reason you're not appending to the `head` instead of the `body`?

Comment: I expect that will still log out 231, just like the second example.

Comment: @DavidThomas: I'm with Karolis. It's not that the script element isn't inserted immediately after the one that's executing (it is, at least on Chrome, according to dev tools), it's the fact that appending a `script` element in that way triggers an *asynchronous* operation to download the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's the only way to force the script to load during the page parsing. Or at least, the only way I'd be willing to believe worked well cross-browser.

If your script were like this, I could see your thinking:

```
<script>
var x = document.createElement("script");
x.src = "console.log.1.js";
x.async = false;
x.defer = false;
document.body.appendChild(x);
</script>
<script><!-- note the new script element -->
console.log("2");
console.log("3");
</script>
```

...because in theory, when the parser hits the `script` element, it suspends everything (because there might be `document.write` statements) and calls into the JavaScript layer. So you might think, well, adding a `script` element to the end of the `body` at that point would insert it between the two.

But adding a `script` element via `appendChild` is just fundamentally different, it's by nature an asynchronous operation (your code continues while the script is being downloaded, which is not the case with `script` elements in the markup barring the `defer` or `async` attributes). I can't point at any one spec to say why, but the behavior you're seeing is exactly what I'd expect. The treatment of `script` elements inline with the markup is a bit special.

We can see that it's the download that's the issue — at least in Chrome — by comparing the result with using a `script` element with *inline* content.

Using an external file ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/oqawon) | [live source](http://jsbin.com/oqawon/edit)):

```
<script>
console.log("before");
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.src = "http://jsbin.com/avatiw"; // Logs the word "during"
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<script>
console.log("after");
</script>
```

Result:

```
before
after
during
```

Using inline script ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/oqawon) | [live source](http://jsbin.com/oqawon/edit) — note that I've made no attempt to make this cross-browser, it works in Chrome and Firefox as they support the `text` property on `script` elements):

```
<script>
console.log("before");
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.text = "console.log('during');";
    document.body.appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<script>
console.log("after");
</script>
```

Output:

```
before
during
after
```

Comment: Do you have any pointers, specs, etc. or does that come from experience? :) Probably the best place would be looking at the actual source code for firefox/chrome, but that sounds painful.

Comment: @Karolis: Nothing I can really point out, which granted is a bit weak. :-) I updated the answer with a bit more discussion, fwiw.

Comment: I believe it is implied by the HTML5 spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-document-write

Comment: @Tim: Hard to say. While that explains why `document.write` behaves the way it doesn't, it doesn't necessarily tell us why `appendChild` doesn't behave the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that using a LazyLoad plugin was perfect for this use case, i.e.

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined')
    LazyLoad.js('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', function() { 
        initialize(); 
    });
else
    initialize();
```